# What native Perl code replaces `cut`?

Tags: perl, cross-platform

I'm learning Perl as I edit a Perl script to replace Posix OS calls to native Perl functions for cross-platform use on Windows. This code has me stumped:

```
if (defined($OPTIONS)) {
    my ($method,$file) = ($1,$2);
    my $count = `cut -d\\  -f 2 $file | sort | uniq | wc -l`;
}
```

1) Where do `$1` and `$2` come from? This code is inside a function but the function doesn't have any arguments. Also, script itself parses over 70 named arguments, so they're not form the command line.

2) Since I don't know what `$2` is, I'm not sure of the content of `$file`.

3) Whatever the content of `$file`, the `cut` function looks at the second field, as delimited by a backslash, of each line.

4) It looks like the ultimate result is the `$count` of unique instances of whatever `cut` found.

Considering `$file` could be quite large (million lines, multi-hundreds of megabytes), what is the most efficient native Perl code to replace this external call and get the same `$count` value? Also "efficient" is relative. This code is in a tool chain where other stages can run for 2 or 3 days. So, it's not a problem if this code requires 5 or 10 minutes on a large file.

Comment: You'll need to show us what comes before this in the function. My guess is that `$1` and `$2` come from a string match. As to `cut`, see [the man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cut).

Comment: Thanks. Perl has lots of crazy reserved variables. I wasn't sure it $1, $2 were in that category. They now become irrelevant.

Comment: Re man page is how I learned about the delimiter, field and $file values. I'm looking for native Perl code to replace this. Is it as straight forward as open(), <while>, regex the second field, add results to a hash and report size of hash as `$count` when complete? Or does Perl have a better way of doing this?

Comment: *“multi-hundreds of megabytes”* isn't too bad. 500MB would take about five seconds to read from disk, and the associated processing time to extract the second field would be insignificant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$1` `$2` etc. are internal Perl variables that hold the contents of the first, second etc. *captures* from the most recent successful regex pattern match.

This should do what you want. It uses a hash to keep track of all the unique values for the second column, and sets `$count` to the number of different keys when the file has been read through. It's likely to be slightly faster than the tool chain equivalent. Note that it's *untested* as I'm not near a system with Perl at present.

I hope there's something more in the real version of this code, as the only effect this has is to change the values of a couple of local variables which are discarded at the end of the block.

```
if ( defined $OPTIONS ) {
    my ($method, $file) = ($1, $2);
    open my $fh, '<', $file or die qq{Unable to open "$file" for input: $!};
    my %count;
    ++$count{ (split /\\/, $_, 3)[1] } while <$fh>;
    my $count = keys %count;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Borodin. This works. As for the "real version"... this is the real version. It's three lines out of almost 2,300 lines of code. The other variables are used in other places within its function. These lines set the $count, which is also used elsewhere. Without the external references, this script will now run on non-Posix systems without `cut`, `uniq`, `wc`, etc. but maybe a little slower. That's fine.

Comment: Yes. Tested on a small test data set of 200 lines. Testing in production environment will take longer.

Comment: As I wrote, it's likely to be slightly *faster*. But the `$count` variable is accessible only between the `my` declaration and the closing brace on the next line. It's not available outside the `if`. The same applies to your original code.

Comment: Yes, there are two lines of code inside the `if` that use `$count` value. I dropped them from this example for brevity. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Well $1, and $2 are previously defined variables. No telling how/where/why without additional code, but the command can be broken down as follows:

```
my $count = `cut -d\\  -f 2 $file | sort | uniq | wc -l`;
```

> -d, sets the delimiter to \ (\ is used to escape the \ as it is a special character). -f, tells cut to extract the second field (what is between the first and second delimiter)

**Example**:

```
cut -d\\ -f 2 <<< $(echo "FIELD 1\FIELD2\THE_REMAINDER")
```

**Result**

```
FIELD2
```

The remaining commands that go through the pipes are as follows:

`sort` will take the list of fields and order them descending in value.

`uniq` will remove duplicates.

`wc -l` will give you a final total of the number of entries in your list (really it is the number of lines)

So in order to replicate this with a non-unix based solution you need to complete each of those steps systematically via `Perl`. This should not be hard to accomplish so I have omitted that part. Feel free to update your question with what you have tried and Im sure there will be a ton of assistance provided as this is a pretty interesting challenge IMHO.

Comment: I don't see the point of `sort` here, especially *before* `uniq`, if the result is just a line count. Also, `sort` sorts in *ascending* order.

Comment: MattSizzle. I got most of that from cut's manpage. I'm trying to replace the line with native Perl so that it runs on Windows. Yet, I'm not familiar with Perl.